# Как склеить большое количество видео фрагментов Python

Tags: python, видео

Имеются множество видеофрагментов (Допустим 100. Название файлов имеет порядковый номер от 0 до 99. Всё файлы имеют расширение .mp4).
Суть вопроса, как правильно реализовать склейку n-ого колличества файлов в 1 ,используя Python?

Comment: https://russianblogs.com/article/43681166854/

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato особенно порадовал вот этот вот фрагмент: "...а конец распускает цветы..." )))